# Recovering files without .encfs6.xml

Tags: linux, encryption, backup

I've lost my `.encfs6.xml` file for a encfs volume.  I still know my passphrase.  Is there anyway to regenerate the `.encfs6.xml` based on similar volumes and the passphrase?  Any chance of brute-forcing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The passphrase is completely irrelevant if you've lost the master key. Imagine you had a treasure trove locked in a huge safe and you've locked the key to that safe in a locker. The treasure trove is your encfs volume, the key to the locker is your passphrase. The locker is gone now. The key to the locker that has the safe key is of no use when you're trying to get into the safe and don't have the locker with the safe key in it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had lost the `.encfs6.xml` due to file system corruption on a failing drive (the drive still worked but there were read/write errors, fsck just made things worse). I ended up using [foremost](http://foremost.sourceforge.net/) to search for all xml files.  It found two copies of the `.encfs6.xml`
.

Comment: Good job! I hope they were the right copies.